# Why I get "RuntimeError: CUDA error: the launch timed out and was terminated" when using Google Cloud compute engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pytorch, google-compute-engine, nvidia, yolo

I have a Google cloud compute engine with 4 Nvidia K80 GPU and Ubuntu 20.04 (python 3.8). When I try to train the yolo5 model, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA error: the launch timed out and was terminated
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
[W CUDAGuardImpl.h:113] Warning: CUDA warning: the launch timed out and was terminated (function destroyEvent)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'c10::CUDAError'
  what():  CUDA error: the launch timed out and was terminated
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
Exception raised from create_event_internal at ../c10/cuda/CUDACachingAllocator.cpp:1230 (most recent call first):
frame #0: c10::Error::Error(c10::SourceLocation, std::string) + 0x42 (0x7f62be2c17d2 in /home/cheyuxuanll/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libc10.so)
frame #1: <unknown function> + 0x239de (0x7f62f6ea69de in /home/cheyuxuanll/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libc10_cuda.so)
frame #2: c10::cuda::CUDACachingAllocator::raw_delete(void*) + 0x22d (0x7f62f6ea857d in /home/cheyuxuanll/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libc10_cuda.so)
frame #3: <unknown function> + 0x300568 (0x7f63736d9568 in /home/cheyuxuanll/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so)
frame #4: c10::TensorImpl::release_resources() + 0x175 (0x7f62be2aa005 in /home/cheyuxuanll/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libc10.so)
frame #5: std::vector<c10d::Reducer::Bucket, std::allocator<c10d::Reducer::Bucket> >::~vector() + 0x2e9 (0x7f62fa8ca5e9 in /home/cheyuxuanll/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
frame #6: c10d::Reducer::~Reducer() + 0x205 (0x7f62fa8bcd25 in /home/cheyuxuanll/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
frame #7: std::_Sp_counted_ptr<c10d::Reducer*, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_dispose() + 0x12 (0x7f6373bb7212 in /home/cheyuxuanll/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so)
frame #8: std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() + 0x46 (0x7f63735c7506 in /home/cheyuxuanll/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so)
frame #9: <unknown function> + 0x7e182f (0x7f6373bba82f in /home/cheyuxuanll/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so)
frame #10: <unknown function> + 0x1f5b20 (0x7f63735ceb20 in /home/cheyuxuanll/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so)
frame #11: <unknown function> + 0x1f6cce (0x7f63735cfcce in /home/cheyuxuanll/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so)
frame #12: /usr/bin/python3() [0x5d1ec4]
frame #13: /usr/bin/python3() [0x5a958d]
frame #14: /usr/bin/python3() [0x5ed1a0]
frame #15: /usr/bin/python3() [0x544188]
frame #16: /usr/bin/python3() [0x5441da]
frame #17: /usr/bin/python3() [0x5441da]
frame #18: PyDict_SetItemString + 0x538 (0x5ce7c8 in /usr/bin/python3)
frame #19: PyImport_Cleanup + 0x79 (0x685179 in /usr/bin/python3)
frame #20: Py_FinalizeEx + 0x7f (0x68040f in /usr/bin/python3)
frame #21: Py_RunMain + 0x32d (0x6b7a1d in /usr/bin/python3)
frame #22: Py_BytesMain + 0x2d (0x6b7c8d in /usr/bin/python3)
frame #23: __libc_start_main + 0xf3 (0x7f6378be40b3 in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)
frame #24: _start + 0x2e (0x5fb12e in /usr/bin/python3)
```

I am training this model with this command:

```
python3 -m torch.distributed.run  --nproc_per_node 4 train.py --batch 16 --data coco128.yaml --weights yolov5s.pt --device 0,1,2,3
```

Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: We got a similar problem right around the time you posted this question. According to our logs Google restarted the server for updates. Reinstalling CUDA helped.

Comment: Hi @CruelCow
, can I reinstall cuda using this: pip3 install torch==1.11.0+cu113 torchvision==0.12.0+cu113 torchaudio===0.11.0+cu113 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch_stable.html

Answer (score 0):

We are also running CUDA in the Google Cloud and our server restarted roughly when you posted your question. While we couldn't detect any changes, our service couldn't start due to "RuntimeError: No CUDA GPUs are available".
So there are some similarities, but also some differences.

Anyway, we opted for the good ol' uninstall and reinstall and that fixed it:

Uninstall:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove "*cublas*" "cuda*" "nsight*"
sudo apt-get --purge remove "*nvidia*"
```

Plus deleting anything in /usr/local/*cuda*

Install:

```
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/debian11/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/debian11/x86_64/ /"
sudo add-apt-repository contrib
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda-11-3
```

We also reinstalled CUDNN, but that may or may not be part of your stack.